# Why is "the pharmacy" supposed to be appropriate in the context? What about "a pharmacy", "pharmacies", or "pharmacy"?

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

I've been studying English for many years, but still struggling with learning the usage of English articles.  Below is one example.

From a news article I read on [this site](https://japantoday.com/category/features/health/how-some-drugs-can-turn-into-a-cancer-causing-chemical-in-the-body).

> How some drugs can turn into a cancer-causing chemical in the body
> By
> C Michael White, University of Connecticut
>
> NEW YORK - When consumers get a prescription drug from ***the*** pharmacy,
> they assume that it’s been tested and is safe to use. But what if a
> drug changes in harmful ways as it sits on the shelf or in the body?

I thought of the following 4 possibilities in terms of articles combined with countable or uncountable noun form of "pharmacy".

1. When consumers get a prescription drug from ***the*** pharmacy, they
   assume that
2. When consumers get a prescription drug from ***a*** pharmacy, they assume that
3. When consumers get a prescription drug from ***pharmacies***, they assume that
4. When consumers get a prescription drug from ***pharmacy***, they assume that

Could you explain why No.1 is supposed to be appropriate in the context? Is there anything wrong with the rest three?

Comment: I suppose the definite article implies 'their local pharmacy'. (2) works equally well. (3) would only work if the plural _prescription drugs_ was used. (4) doesn't work at all.